# How do I show off-screen elements in Expression Blend/VS2013?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

I've got a page in Expression Blend (Windows Phone) that has a large stackpanel which scrolls.

I want to be able to see the elements **in designer** which are scrolled off screen. All I've been able to get is something like this:
[image: doesn't show rendered element]
which of course isn't what I want. Same effect in both Visual Studio 2013. Fit to Selection, Ctrl+9 - tried them both in both applications.

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up in your namespaces you should have something like `mc:Ignorable="d"` where next to it you can put `d:DesignWidth="1000"` (or whatever size you want) to expand the area only for design time.

You can do the same with Height if you like via `d:DesignHeight`

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: PERFECT. I had played w/ the d: but was using Height, not DesignHeight. This worked swimmingly. Thank you